# How come '%' in my code produces another number than the one I get when calculating myself?

Tags: c#, modulo

I have my code get me the number of digits of an entered number.
But if I dial it by hand I get another ...

Let's take 125 and - for example- modulate it by 10. Let's even put that in a while loop and let our number be divided by 10 each round.
We get:

```
125%10 -> 5
12,5%10 -> 2,5
1,25%10 -> 1,25
```

Our sum would be 8,75.
But if I use the code down below we get 8.

Does anyone know why it is that different?

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace EvenOrOdd
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int num, sum = 0, r;
            Console.WriteLine("\nEnter a Number : ");
            num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            while (num != 0)
            {
                r = num % 10;
                num = num / 10;
                sum = sum + r;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Sum of Digits of the Number : " + sum);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're parsing the numbers into an `int` which means that the numbers get rounded off.

Comment: `12,5%10 -> 2,5` How would you store 2.5 in an `int`?

Comment: You use an integer (int) to store your result. Integers cant display decimal places so it simply saves your 8.75 as 8. Change your int up for a float and you should get your desired result with decimal places.

Comment: @elgonzo I see it now. He enters an integer number and then try to sum the remainders. Then the first two comments applies.

Comment: `Sum of Digits of the Number` Without understanding the context I would **expect** it to be 8 (1+2+5) - especially if this is homework.

Comment: @Steve, correct. Now i see it too. The code iterates over `num`, dividing it by 10 in every iteration. Doh! I need new glasses ;-)

Comment: @elgonzo 125 is being entered. The other values is what he/she is expecting to occur on each loop iteration.

Comment: As others have said, you are using integer math. Not only does it apply to the `%` modulo operation, but also to the division. If `int num = 125` then `num / 10` will evaluate to `12` (because any fraction will simply be truncated from a number in integer math)

Comment: Thank you everyone! It seems not only my datatype, but also my logic was bit off, thanks for resolving that~
@mjwills ... it's mostly about a little number game i tried programming where i need **integer** only, but i thought too far and false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace EvenOrOdd
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            decimal num, sum = 0, r;
            Console.WriteLine("\nEnter a Number : ");
            num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            while (num >= 1)
            {
                r = num % 10;
                num = num / 10;
                sum = sum + r;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Sum of Digits of the Number : " + sum);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

There are 2 issues here

-

1. `int num, sum = 0, r; to be changed to decimal num, sum = 0, r;`, this will make the decimals to be considered
2. This logic seems to be another issue `while (num != 0)`, the following will be the iteration results

   - `Iteration1 - 125 Mod 10 = 5`
   - `Iteration2 - 12.5 Mod 10 = 2.5`
   - `Iteration3 - 1.25 Mod 10 = 1.25`
   - `Iteration4 - 0.125 Mod 10 = 0.125`

and goes on as 0.125 is != 0 this will continue

Comment: Thank you! You're totally right, my logic also was pretty off here, thanks for pointing that out! :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use a floating point type, like float or double. An `int` cant hold the number "8.75".

Just replace `int` with `double` or `float` and it should work.